# Introspector finding properties that no longer exist

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, introspection

I'm relying on introspection for XML processing in a Java EE 6 app I've been working on for quite a while. So far it has worked just fine. However, I had to rename a property setter name. The problem is, `Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>)` is detecting both the old and the new setters, even after I

- stopped using JRebel,
- purged my Maven repository,
- blew away GlassFish and installed a fresh one, and
- rebuilt my web app.

Also, I ensured the introspector's cache is flushed:

```java
public class BeanUtils {
    public static Map<String, Class> propertyTypes(Class beanType) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Class> propertyTypes = new HashMap<>();
        for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanType).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            propertyTypes.put(descriptor.getName(), descriptor.getPropertyType());
        }
        return propertyTypes;
    }
    // Added this to flush the introspector
    static {
        Introspector.flushCaches();
    }
}
```

Here is the class I'm introspecting:

```java
public class AdhocUnavailableTimesRequestTag
{
    public AdhocUnavailableTimeRequestTag[] getAdhocUnavailableTimes()
    {
        return adhocUnavailableTimes;
    }

    public void setUnavailableTimes(AdhocUnavailableTimeRequestTag[] adhocUnavailableTimes)
    {
        this.adhocUnavailableTimes = adhocUnavailableTimes;
    }

    private AdhocUnavailableTimeRequestTag[] adhocUnavailableTimes;
}
```

And calling `BeanUtils.propertyTypes(AdhocUnavailableTimesRequestTag.class)` returns:

```
"adhocUnavailableTimes" => class [LAdhocUnavailableTimeRequestTag;
"class" => java.lang.Class"
"unavailableTimes" => class [LAdhocUnavailableTimeRequestTag;
```

What could be causing the introspector to pick up `unavailableTimes` when it no longer exists? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Oh shit! I think I'll delete this one as the only lesson learnt is don't be stupid. Thanks for pointing out my stupidity.

Comment: Shit occasionally happens to everyone :) You just needed a pair of fresh eyes here.

Comment: May as well put your comment in an answer. I won't delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the name of the method `setUnavailableTimes`. You fix it by renaming the method to `setAdhocUnavailableTimes`.

Comment: Thanks for your fresh pair of eyes.